# jQuery autocomplete outputs all the results instead of matching string

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am newer to JSON and jQuery . I need to do a jQuery autocomplete, for this I put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#executives').autocomplete({source:'search_executives.php', minLength:2});
});
</script>
```

And in HTML :

```
<div class="rows">
    <div class="labels">Search</div>
    <div class="textboxs" style=" width: 175px;"><input id="executives" name="executive" /></div>
</div>
```

My `search_executives.php` is :

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
        header('Location:index.php');
        exit();
    }
include_once('include/config.php'); 

$qry = "SELECT employee_id,fname,mname,lname FROM personal_details WHERE deg_id = '1'";

$res = $dbo->executeQuery( $qry ) ;

//$results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $res ); $i++ )
{
    $result[] = array( 'label' => $res[$i]['fname'].' '.$res[$i]['mname'].' '.$res[$i]['lname'] , 'value' => $res[$i]['employee_id'] ) ;
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Now my problem is -

1. It outputs all the results, it does not depend on the search string I have entered.
2. It prints the `value` ( e.g. 3 ) in the textfield in HTML. I need to print the name of the executives with his `employee_id` as his value.

NB: 1st Part is solved. I forgot to add the `LIKE` condition in `SQL` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to set the value of the input as the `label`, and then have another field to store the `employee_id` when an item has been selected:

```
select: function(e, ui) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.value = ui.item.label;
  $('#other_field').val(ui.item.value);
}
```

#### [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ESTgB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are working with an **input text box.**

The value attribute of the textbox appears in the front end textbox and you cannot change it. (ie) employee_id in your case.

Comment: What I need to do if I want the `label` to be displayed in text box with `value` attribute from `php` as its valu ?